# System owns this folder

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions, file-association, user-profiles

Occasionally I get messages telling me I can't access, modify or delete specific files and folders, even when I am an admin. For example the windows.old folder because system owns it.

I am on Windows 10, I know you can go into each separate folder which is owned by system and set it that you own it.

Is there a way to do this for all folders instead of having to go into each individual folder and add yourself into the owner list, like adding yourself into the system group or something.

I don't care if it takes an entire day, like a command in cmd that will give me ownership to all folders.

Comment: Taking ownership of every file and folder on your system will have serious side effects resulting in a broken system and in the end serves no purpose but certainly possible

Comment: How would it @Ramhound

Comment: Answer is "No".

Comment: @Foxhound, because when you are the owner, the system is no longer the owner, and it might try to do things that are no longer possible without being owner. There is the risk that your system will not work as it should - I think the chance is small, but I would not risk my system for that. Instead, consider adding your ID with full access to all files. You don't need to be the owner to be able to do things.

Comment: If you do this, the next question you'll be asking is "What is TrustedInstaller, why does it need permission to access my folders & why is everything now broken?"

Answer (score 0):

Use takeown - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755342%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Do a full backup first just in case.